# Qt QTreeView mouse entered/left event?

Tags: qt, qt-events

There is a "entered" signal for a QTreeView Widget, which I can use to check if my mouse moves over an item.

Is there a way to implement an "left" signal?

Why:
I have a treeView with a lot of items which I also plot via QChart. I want to highlight the plot when someone mouse over the data in the treeview. 
I can highlight it via the "entered" signal, but I have no idea how to change it back to the default if the mouse left/mouse is over another item...

Comment: what is "left" signal?

Answer (score 0):

`entered` is a member of `QAbstractItemView`. You should probably reimplement `QAbstractItemView::dragLeaveEvent` virtual method.

See this method documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragLeaveEvent